# Django query count wrong

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model (called `MyModel` here) where I do

```
MyModel.objects.filter(value__exact='').delete()
```

to delete all objects with a blank `value` (`value` is a TextField with `blank=True`).
However there seem to disappear more objects when I do this, than the count I get before deleting with

```
MyModel.objects.filter(value__exact='').count()
```

If I count blank valued `MyOModel` objects with a loop, using

```
count = 0
for obj in MyModel.objects.iterator():
    if not obj.value or obj.value.strip() == '':
        count += 1
```

I only get very few extra objects, compared tothe above count.

**What can cause this?**

I have checked related models that are referencing `MyModel` if they could cascade and somehow delete instances of `MyModel` without blank values. This is not the case.

I'm on Django 1.8.7.

**UPDATE**

To add to the mysticism I have now tried to delete in a for loop:

```
count = 0
for attribute_value in AttributeValue.objects.filter(value__exact=''):
    attribute_value.delete()
    count += 1
```

The `count` variable comes out with the expected number of deleted `MyModel` objects, but still

```
MyModel.objects.filter(value__exact='').count()
```

comes out with a lower number than expected. In fact it seems like there was deleted more than three times the number of objects expected.

I have also tried the following for the count (see comments)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(value='').count()
MyModel.objects.filter(value=u'').count()
```

with same results for counts.

Comment: Note that the number returned by Django after a delete is the count of objects **and** related objects that were deleted. Maybe that's what's confusing you.

Comment: The queries check for an empty string. It doesn't automagically strip spaces from the row value.

Comment: `if not obj.value or obj.value.strip() == ''` This also includes strings containing only whitespace as well as `None`, if that is possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without knowing what your actual data, it's hard to know what's going on here.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I check the difference on `MyModel.objects.count()` before and after the delete operation ;)

Comment: @HåkenLid That is going to be hard. Time is not on my side, and I have only experienced this on some customer data I have here. I have more than 130000 of the object type I have designated `MyModel` above, and a hacked relation table (to a third model NOT using ManyToManyField, and NOT made by me) with over 700000 relation objects. I was hoping someone had experiences similar issues, so I could gain from their experience.

Comment: @knbk That is my expectation and experience prior to this too, and this is why I am puzzled when more objects than counted on the same filter is deleted. I am hoping someone more experienced than me can give their experience on possible pitfalls here.

Comment: Still, the query only counts the values that are exactly the empty string `""`, so the equivalent is `count = sum(obj.value == "" for obj in Mymodel.objects.iterator())`. You could be counting values such as `"\n"` or `None` as well in your loop there.

Comment: I have now tried with `MyModel.objects.filter(value='').count()` and since I'm on Python 2, I also tried `MyModel.objects.filter(value=u'').count()` and I still get the same count before deleting. 

Note: I want all blank valued objects gone, so it is ok that `'\n'` and `None` get deleted too. There is however no objects with `value == None`.

Answer (score 0):

This will sort your problem

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
```

To get all the value fields which contain something

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(value_length=Length('value')).filter(value_length=0)
```

To get all the values which are not null

MyModel.objects.annotate(value_length=Length('value')).filter(value_length__gt=0)

You can also do this way

```
MyModel.objects.filter(value='',value__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Your first option seems overcomplicated. Regarding your second option, `value` is not nullable, and you need to use `Q` objects to issue a logical `or`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit in another model with an unnoticed foreign to `MyModel`. The reason why I didn't look there was that this model in my setup is references by `MyModel` too, and PyCharm somehow missed the relation (or I did in the PyCharm GUI). The new version of PyCharm which just came now fixed it for me.

Sorry for the confusion.